# CSS break-word won't with string full of dot, inside a <p> without !important

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm coming to you because I'm fighting for 2 hours with (in CSS):

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

If my sentence is full of dot (.................... etc), this line will not break, inside a `<p></p>` (work with `<span></span>`)

The div parents have the following css:

```
.container-body {
    width: 80%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Also, the div parent get `display:block` when slideDown jquery is executed (`<div style="display:block;" class="container-body">`)

if I add `!important` to `break-word`, it will work.

How can I fix this without using `!important` ?

Thanks !

But if I add `!important` (which is not good), it work.

Comment: Please, may you show an example of this behaviour somewhere? Such as https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You have other CSS somewhere that is interfering with this one. Is this in a CMS like Wordpress or something?

Comment: No it's my own code, I try to reproduice it in jsfiddle (I eat)

Comment: Sounds like you're battling [CSS specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)

Comment: p {
margin:0;
padding:0;
display: inline-block;
} <=== My mistake, I found this using jsfiddle, the question can be close, sorry about it.